# I have already encoded byte arrays & i want to create mp4 video. is MediaMuxer is helpful?. can i use MediaMuxer without Mediacodec?

Tags: android, mp4, video-processing, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I have live encoded byte stream from which i just need to create `.mp4` file. how can I do that?.

I found people are using `MediaMuxer` API along with **MediaCodec** but I do
not need to use MediaCodec as I already have encoded frames.

Is it possible with `MediaMuxer` API only? I do not want to use any library for this.

Comment: I don't use Android SDK but [the first code example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer) seems self-explanatory. What is not making sense to you? For easier testing I would skip the audio part and just try to encode frames. Try one keyframe (so you're making a 1 frame or even 1 second MP4 for practice) This is the main line `muxer.writeSampleData(currentTrackIndex, inputBuffer, bufferInfo);` where **inputBuffer** is your frame bytes.  **currentTrackIndex** is acquired earlier in the code and **bufferInfo** is created by you (see the docs about bufferInfo).

Comment: I followed above api.  here i have to get currentTrackIndex which i am getting from mTrackIndex = mMuxer!!.addTrack(format); where format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", mFrameBufferWidth, mFrameBufferHeight).

and BufferInfo object is created by mBufferInfo?.set(0, size, 0, 0);

by using this i get mp4 file which can not be played & size is 582B always